# Displaying error login message in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web

I'm trying to display an error message in my index.jsp page, if a user makes an invalid login.

Here is my servlet code:

```
if( passwordService.authenticate(password, attemptedPassword, salt)){


        User user = LogicFacade.login(email, password);

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("user", user);
        session.setAttribute("role", user.getRole());

        return user.getRole() + "page";  // i return the name of the jsp page, to get to the next jsp page

    }else{

    //here I make the error message I want to show
        String errorMessage ="The retrived password or username did not match";
        request.setAttribute("errorMessage", errorMessage );
           RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
                rd.forward(request, response);  
    }

}       catch (SQLException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException | ServletException | IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;

}
}
```

Here I display it in my jsp:

```
 <%
if(null!=request.getAttribute("errorMessage"))
{
    out.println(request.getAttribute("errorMessage"));
    out.println("<p> Error!! </p>");
    //ved godt det ikke er super smart at printe paragraph tags med ud
}

 %>
```

Why does the message not show?

Comment: because you haven't defined `out`

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte `out` do not need to be declared in `jsp`

Comment: is it forwarding to index.jsp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this may solve your problem

```
   if(!request.getAttribute("hello").equals(null))
```